# object has no attribute when using tatsu API

Tags: discord.py

I am going to create a discordpy bot that can check users server credit of Tatsu bot
I use Tatsu API to get user's credit, but it has problem that is 'object has no attribute 'credits''. It also appears when I use avatar_url, avatar_hash,...
This is Tatsu library: https://github.com/PumPum7/Tatsu.py

```
@commands.command()
    async def transfer(self,ctx, member: discord.Member):
      wrapper = ApiWrapper(key=os.environ['token'])
      user_profile = await wrapper.get_profile(member.id)
      await ctx.send(user_profile.credits)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at the source code of the library (it's a really bad one to be honest). It seems that when an internal exception is throw, instead of raising and propagating it, the author decided to return it (exact lines are [here](https://github.com/PumPum7/Tatsu.py/blob/master/tatsu/wrapper.py#L26-L29)), I have no idea what the author wanted to do with that, nonetheless you can use a simple if-statement to check if the method didn't return an error:

```py
@commands.command()
async def transfer(self,ctx, member: discord.Member):
    wrapper = ApiWrapper(key=os.environ['token'])
    user_profile = await wrapper.get_profile(member.id)
    if not isinstance(user_profile, Exception):
        await ctx.send(user_profile.credits)
    else:
        exc = user_profile
        print(f"An error happened:\n{exc.__class__.__name__}: {exc}")
```